# A JavaScript function to populate innerHTML based on country language

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I typically use JavaScript for UI/interaction purposes, and I'm trying to improve my skills by trying to write more complicated JS.

I have written the following code in an attempt to change the content in our site's country selector based on the URL and country code.

I know it's atrocious, but I have spent hours and hours and I'm stuck. If anyone can offer information that can help me push forward, I will really appreciate it.

All of my variables are unused, and that's because I thought I could use dot notation to call them inside of my if statements but that's not true.

Here's what I have written so far. Try not to laugh (or cry). And thank you.

```
//Initialize Variables
var moduleTitle = document.querySelector(".amt-select-title").innerHTML;
var colTitle = document.querySelector(".amt-choose-country-col > h3").innerHTML;
var languageModTitle = document.querySelector(".amt-choose-language > h2").innerHTML;
var investorRelations = document.querySelector(".amt-utility-3 a").innerHTML;
var company = document.querySelector(".amt-utility-4 a").innerHTML;
var corporateResponsibility = document.querySelector(".amt-utility-5 a").innerHTML;
var careers = document.querySelector(".amt-utility-6 a").innerHTML;
var contactUs = document.querySelector(".amt-utility-7 a").innerHTML;

// This is my library of objects -- one for each language -- EN, ES, PT and DE
var ENcontent = {
moduleTitle : "English Module Title",
colTitle : "English Title",
languageModTitle : "Choose Language EN Title",
investorRelations : "Investor Relations",
company : "Company",
corporateResponsibility : "Corporate Responsbility",
careers : "Careers",
contactUs : "Contact Us"    
};
var EScontent = {
    moduleTitle : "Spanish Module Title",
    colTitle : "Spanish Title",
    languageModTitle : "Choose Language ES Title",
    investorRelations : "Relaciones con Inversionistas",
    company : "Empresa",
    corporateResponsibility : "Responsabilidad Corporativa",
    careers : "Oportunidades Laborales",
    contactUs : "Contáctanos"    
};
var PTcontent = {
    moduleTitle : "Portuguese Module Title",
    colTitle : "Portuguese Title",
    languageModTitle : "Choose Language PT Title",
    investorRelations : "Investidores",
    company : "Empresa",
    corporateResponsibility : "Responsabilidade Corporativa",
    careers : "Carreiras",
    contactUs : "Fale Conosco"    
};

var DEcontent = {
    moduleTitle : "German Module Title",
    colTitle : "German Title",
    languageModTitle : "Choose Language DE Title",
    investorRelations : "Investor Relations",
    company : "Unternehmen",
    corporateResponsibility : "Corporate Responsbility",
    careers : "Karriere",
    contactUs : "Kontakt"    
};

//Language Object
function Language(moduleTitle, colTitle, languageModTitle, investorRelations, company, corporateResponsibility, careers, contactUs) {      
this.moduleTitle = moduleTitle,
this.colTitle = colTitle,
this.languageModTitle = languageModTitle,
this.investorRelations = investorRelations,
this.company = company,
this.corporateResponsibility = corporateResponsibility,
this.careers = careers,
this.contactUs = contactUs;    
}

//Calling Language() function using arguments based on country -- What's a good way to do this? 
if(window.location.href.indexOf("/en") > -1) {
Language( 
    ENcontent.moduleTitle, 
        ENcontent.colTitle, 
        ENcontent.languageModTitle, 
        ENcontent.investorRelations, 
        ENcontent.company, 
        ENcontent.corporateResponsibility, 
        ENcontent.careers, 
        ENcontent.contactUs);
}else if(window.location.href.indexOf("/es") > -1) {
    Language(
        EScontent.moduleTitle, 
        EScontent.colTitle, 
        EScontent.languageModTitle, 
        EScontent.investorRelations, 
        EScontent.company, 
        EScontent.corporateResponsibility, 
        EScontent.careers, EScontent.contactUs);
}else if(window.location.href.indexOf("/pt") > -1) {
    Language( 
        PTcontent.moduleTitle, 
        PTcontent.colTitle,  
        PTcontent.languageModTitle,  
        PTcontent.investorRelations,  
        PTcontent.company,  
        PTcontent.corporateResponsibility,  
        PTcontent.careers,  
        PTcontent.contactUs);
}else if(window.location.href.indexOf("/de") > -1) {
    Language(
        DEcontent.moduleTitle, 
        DEcontent.colTitle,  
        DEcontent.languageModTitle,  
        DEcontent.investorRelations,  
        DEcontent.company,  
        DEcontent.corporateResponsibility,  
        DEcontent.careers,  
        DEcontent.contactUs);
}
```

Comment: You really should use an existing library to do internationalization for you. One would be fnando/i18n-js, which has a focus on Ruby but it works stand-alone as well (see the ["vanilla JS" setup section](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js#vanilla-javascript)). Another one would be http://i18njs.com/ which might be a little simpler to begin with. There are many others, there is no need to re-invent the wheel here.

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Comment: @user3472810 when you say you are "stuck" are you having a specific issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, I'll offer you a quick fix. Write your `Language` function as so:

```
function Language(moduleTitle, colTitle, languageModTitle, investorRelations, company, corporateResponsibility, careers, contactUs) {      
 document.querySelector(".amt-select-title").innerHTML = moduleTitle,
 document.querySelector(".amt-choose-country-col > h3").innerHTML = colTitle,
 document.querySelector(".amt-choose-language > h2").innerHTML = languageModTitle,
 document.querySelector(".amt-utility-3 a").innerHTML = investorRelations,
 document.querySelector(".amt-utility-4 a").innerHTML = company,
 document.querySelector(".amt-utility-5 a").innerHTML = corporateResponsibility,
 document.querySelector(".amt-utility-6 a").innerHTML = careers,
 document.querySelector(".amt-utility-7 a").innerHTML = contactUs;   

}
```

This should update the page accordingly. However, you might want to look into Object references in JS (primitive vs objects). Particularly, in the case of using the keywords `this` inside functions and the `window` property (Global objects). For instance:

```
var obj = {a: "Hello"};
var str = obj.a; // str === obj.a returns true
str = "World" // str === obj.a returns false
```

This is because `obj.a` is not linked to `str`. We are merely passing the actual value around.

However, note how this is different:

```
var obj1 = {a: "Hello"};
var obj2 = obj1; // obj2.a === obj1.a returns true
obj2.a = "World" // obj2.a === obj1.a  STILL returns true
```

When you assign objects to a variable, you are passing a reference. When you assign primitives to a variable, you're passing its value!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're on the right track but there are a few ways to clean this up. First of all, when you call the `Language` function you do not need to pass through each value of the object. You can simply loop through the object and assign each value to the innerHTML of each section in your DOM:

```
Language(content) {
  for (key in content) {
    this[key] = content[key];
  }
}
```

That should clean things up a bit. The next issue is that you are not binding any context to the `Language` function. Simply calling `this[key]` will look for the key in the window, since `this` is bound to the window as written. Instead, you can pass through the DOM elements you're targeting as parameters:

```
var targets = {
  moduleTitle: document.querySelector(".amt-select-title"),
  colTitle: document.querySelector(".amt-choose-country-col > h3"),
  languageModTitle: document.querySelector(".amt-choose-language > h2"),
  investorRelations: document.querySelector(".amt-utility-3 a"),
  company = document.querySelector(".amt-utility-4 a"),
  corporateResponsibility: document.querySelector(".amt-utility-5 a"),
  careers: document.querySelector(".amt-utility-6 a"),
  contactUs: document.querySelector(".amt-utility-7 a")
}

Language(content, targets) {
  for (key in content) {
    target[key].innerHTML = content[key];
  }
}

Language(ENcontent, targets);
```

I hope this helps and answers your question!